# convert the json UTC time format into CST - in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have done a code to convert json UTC time format to CST. But i am seeing 2 different UTC format of time in my input file. i use the below code to convert to CST.

```
  `date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(sline[i], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")`
```

THis is working for

```
 `2021-06-11T19:30:32.42Z`
```

but not working for

```
 `2021-06-11T15:26:31Z`
```

How can i have multiple format of datatime.striptime for same field?? Any suggestion???

Thanks..
-Prasanna.K

Comment: note that your strptime format is wrong; correct would be `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"`, i.e. parsing the `Z` from the input to UTC (instead of ignoring it by setting a literal 'Z').

Answer (score 0):

[dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s parser does a good job handling the different input formats:

```
import dateutil

ts = ["2021-06-11T19:30:32.42Z", "2021-06-11T15:26:31Z"]
to_tz = dateutil.tz.gettz("US/Central")

# to datetime / UTC and then to desired time zone in one step:
dts = [dateutil.parser.parse(s).astimezone(to_tz) for s in ts]

# dts
# [datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 11, 14, 30, 32, 420000, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central')),
#  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 11, 10, 26, 31, tzinfo=tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Central'))]

for d in dts:
    print(d)

# 2021-06-11 14:30:32.420000-05:00
# 2021-06-11 10:26:31-05:00
```